# What are the valid values for -webkit-appearance

Tags: css, html, webkit

I'm playing around with a CSS-only styled `<audio>` element for `-webkit-` devices, and have noticed that the slider is styled natively as:

```
::webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  -webkit-appearance: media-slider;
 ...
}
```

I know that `none` is a valid value, but are there any others and if so, what are they? I can't find any documentation about it.

The ultimate goal for me is to have a purely CSS-styled audio element across multiple browsers. I'm working on -webkit- as it's the one I noticed I can do it on first; -moz- and -ms- are what I plan on testing out next.

Comment: almost every values for -webkit-appearence [here](http://trentwalton.com/2010/07/14/css-webkit-appearance/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266-_webkit_appearance)

```
button
button-bevel
caret
checkbox
default-button
listbox
listitem
media-fullscreen-button
media-mute-button
media-play-button
media-seek-back-button
media-seek-forward-button
media-slider
media-sliderthumb
menulist
menulist-button
menulist-text
menulist-textfield
none
push-button
radio
searchfield
searchfield-cancel-button
searchfield-decoration
searchfield-results-button
searchfield-results-decoration
slider-horizontal
slider-vertical
sliderthumb-horizontal
sliderthumb-vertical
square-button
textarea
textfield
```